# How do I force Azure Apps to use latest html file?

Tags: html, azure, web, flask

I have a web application hosted on azure apps that I publish using visual studio. It is a flask app. One of the templates is called searchresult.html. I am making changes to this file that are made when I run locally. When I run it on the server though the changes are absent.

Using the azure console I can see that the changes are present in the file that is stored on the server, but the application continues to deliver the old html.

How can I force azure to see my updated file?

Things I have tried:

1. Deleting the file directly on the server and re-publishing it
2. Committing changes to git, even though I knew that would do nothing
3. Testing it locally (it works)
4. Restarting the application

Comment: You need to reboot the app in order to present changed html files. Apart from that, sometimes there's still some junk in your cache which might influence your browsers behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you already check the file has been changed on the Kudu, so it supposed not an issue of deployment. You could disable caching in your browser.

such as in chrome browser, navigate to F11 window and select the `Disable cache` blanket.

[image]

or please try to access your website via `incognito` model.

In addition, I crashed into similar issue with you in other web app. My previous solution is that enable `always on` option on the portal and restart my app, it worked.

Just for your reference.Hope it helps you.